# Angular Material Icons Registration in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

I am new to angular material, just want to use its icons, have been reading about it but says I have to register it but don't know exactly how to get the set of svg icons.
What I did:
1. downloaded icons from by using the **[URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROCD1.png)**

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROCD1.png): http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/ from the section [image]
2. Placed all the icons under md/icons/..... and configured it as

```
.config(function ($mdIconProvider) {
  $mdIconProvider.defaultIconSet('md/icons/core-icons.svg', 24);
})
```

But don't know how to get the sets and use them in app. can someone guide me here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## Steps to Setup Google Material Icons with Angular Material

Following these 5 steps, I use Material Icons in projects following Amit Shukla guidelines.

1. In your head element of your index.html.

   ```
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
   ```
2. Within a utilities folder, I set up a custom material module.

   ```
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
   import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
   import { BrowserAnimationsModule,NoopAnimationsModule } from 
   '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
   import {
              MatButtonModule,
              MatCheckboxModule,
              MatFormFieldModule,
              MatDialogModule,
              MatTabsModule,
              MatProgressSpinnerModule,
              MatMenuModule,
              MatIconModule,
              MatInputModule,
              MatSelectModule,
              MatToolbarModule,
              MatCardModule,
              MatChipsModule,
              MatListModule,
              MatTooltipModule,
              MatNativeDateModule,
              MatDatepickerModule,
              MatTableModule,
              MatPaginatorModule,
              MatProgressBarModule,
              MatSortModule,
              MatSnackBarModule,
              MatStepperModule,
              MatGridListModule,
              MatExpansionModule,
              MatRadioModule,
              MatBadgeModule
              } from '@angular/material';
      import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
      import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
      import {DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';
      import {MatIconRegistry} from '@angular/material';
      @NgModule({
          imports: [
              FormsModule,
              ReactiveFormsModule,
              BrowserAnimationsModule,
              MatButtonModule,
           MatCheckboxModule,
           MatFormFieldModule,
           MatDialogModule,
           MatTabsModule,
           MatProgressSpinnerModule,
           MatMenuModule,
           MatIconModule,
           MatInputModule,
           MatSelectModule,
           MatToolbarModule,
           MatCardModule,
           MatChipsModule,
           MatListModule,
           MatTooltipModule,
           MatNativeDateModule,
           MatDatepickerModule,
           MatTableModule,
           MatPaginatorModule,
           MatProgressBarModule,
           MatSortModule,
           MatSnackBarModule,
           MatStepperModule,
           MatGridListModule,
           MatBadgeModule,
           MatExpansionModule,
           MatRadioModule,
           MatBadgeModule
           ],
       exports: [
           BrowserAnimationsModule,
           MatButtonModule,
           MatFormFieldModule,
           MatCheckboxModule,
           MatTabsModule,
           MatProgressSpinnerModule,
           MatMenuModule,
           MatIconModule,
           MatInputModule,
           MatSelectModule,
           MatToolbarModule,
           MatCardModule,
           MatChipsModule,
           MatListModule,
           MatTooltipModule,
           MatNativeDateModule,
           MatDatepickerModule,
           MatTableModule,
           MatPaginatorModule,
           MatProgressBarModule,
           MatSortModule,
           MatSnackBarModule,
           MatStepperModule,
           MatGridListModule,
           MatBadgeModule,
           MatExpansionModule,
           MatRadioModule,
           MatBadgeModule
           ],
       declarations: []
       })
       export class CustommaterialModule {
           constructor(iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, sanitizer:DomSanitizer) 
                {
                   iconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
                       'linkedin',
                       sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('../../assets/icons/linkedin.svg'));
                }
        }
   ```
3. Place your svg icon inside the icons folder which is inside of the assets folder

   ```
   /app
   /assets
      /icons
          linkedin.svg
   ```
4. Add your CustomMaterialModule and BrowserAnimationsModule or NoopAnimationsModule to your imports in your app.module.ts

   ```
   import { BrowserAnimationsModule, NoopAnimationsModule } from 
   '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
   import { CustommaterialModule } from './utilities/custommaterial.module';
   ```
5. Inside your component.html

   ```
   <mat-icon matTooltip="Write any pop up info"
   svgIcon="linkedin">LinkedIn </mat-icon>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

## Google Material Icons

By default, Angular Material supports Google Material Icons, although it won't automatically add the icons for you. (Also, you don't have to use `app.config`!)

1. Add the following line to your `HTML` under `<head>`:

   ```html
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons|Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- <- Note: this also includes the Roboto font -->
   ```

*Note*: More info [here](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icon-font-for-the-web)

2. Use it via the `<md-icon>` directive (Replacing `menu` with the icon that you want; a list of icons are available on [Material.io](https://material.io/tools/icons):

   ```html
   <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
   ```

**Example:**

```js
angular.module('App', ['ngMaterial']);
```

```html
<html ng-app="App">

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons|Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.8/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.8/angular-material.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
</body>

</html>
```

## Icon sets

Alternatively, you can use an icon set. Follow the instructions below:

1. Download the icon set (for example [MaterialDesignIcons > `mdi.svg`](https://materialdesignicons.com/getting-started) and place it somewhere in your project (such as your `assets` folder) which you can get from.

   [image: MaterialDesignIcons - Getting Started (AngularJS Material)]
   [image: <code>assets</code> folder]
2. Add a configuration for declaring the icon set under `app.config`:

   ```js
   angular.module('App', ['ngMaterial'])
       .config(function($mdIconProvider, $sceDelegateProvider) {
           $mdIconProvider.defaultIconSet('path/to/icons.svg');
           // Note: If you want to get a svg iconset from another domain, add $sceDelegateProvider to function as follows:
           $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(
               // Adding 'self' to the whitelist will allow requests from the current origin.
               'self',
               // Allow from all URLs
               // Note: It's recommended to only specify the given domain you want to allow.
               '**'
       )
   })
   ```
3. Use it via the `<md-icon>` directive, but add an `md-svg-icon` attribute to it with the name of the SVG icon you want:

   ```
   <md-icon md-svg-icon="menu"></md-icon>
   ```

**Example**:

```js
    angular.module('App', ['ngMaterial'])
    .config(function($mdIconProvider, $sceDelegateProvider) {
      $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
        'self',
        '**'
      ])
  $mdIconProvider.defaultIconSet('https://edricchan03.github.io/res/mdi.svg');
})
```

```html
<html ng-app="App">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.8/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.8/angular-material.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
</head>

<body>
  <md-icon md-svg-icon="plus"></md-icon>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you please describe the full procedure from scratch.

Comment: And moreover how do I get and register svg set?

Comment: Hi Edric, In the **Icon set** example how do I host the iconset locally, how or from where to download the svg set of icons and use them in my project?

Answer (score 0):

Another way (not including every line of every file for brevity):

1. Add the `MatIconModule` to `app.module.ts`

```
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';

@NgModule({
  imports: [MatIconModule]
})
```

2. Add the `MatIconRegistry` and `DomSanitizer` to `app.component.ts`

```
import { MatIconRegistry } from '@angular/material';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
}
```

3. Add the svg icons you wish to use to the constructor in `AppComponent`

```
import { MatIconRegistry } from '@angular/material';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry, sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    iconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
      'name-of-icon',
      sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('path-to-icon-in-your-app')
    );
  }
}
```

The `name-of-icon` will be the name you use in the html template. The `path-to-icon-in-your-app` is the location in your app where the icon file is located. Ideally, this is in the `assets` folder.

4. Add the icon to your html template, `app.component.html` in this case

```
<mat-icon svgIcon="name-of-icon"></mat-icon>
```

Comment: OP is using the former implementation of AngularJS Material, _not_ Angular Material.

Comment: I suppose I should have inferred that from the `.config` code sample but the OP used the Angular tag and stated they are using Angular Material; the question should be updated to reflect the use of AngularJS Material if in fact that is what they're asking.